# padding-right not working when using writing-mode:vertical-rl and position:absolute in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Here is the code:

```
<div
class="container"
style="position: relative;width: 400px;height: 400px;border: solid black;">
<div
class="content"
style="position: absolute;right: 0;writing-mode: vertical-rl;
padding-right: 50px;">Some text</div>
</div>
```

There are two boxes. I set the border and size of outer box (`.container`). So, we can see it clearly. With the inner box (`.contanet`), I set the `position`, `right`, `padding-right`, and `writing-mode` property. But It layout differently in Chrome and Edge.

It display like this in Microsoft Edge and Firefox.
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LWos.png)
But in Chrome, the right padding of the `.content` goes outside the `.container`.
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgWpL.png)

Is this a known bug of Chrome? And how to fix this issue?

Sorry about my poor english and thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: instead of padding-right, directly use right property and give a try

Comment: Thanks, It's worked, but in my project, I need the offset property to do other positon job, and add the padding additionally.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively try this. Instead of position use display property.

```html
<div
class="container"
style="display:block;text-align:end;width: 400px;height: 400px;border: solid black;">
<div
class="content"
style="display:inline-block;right: 0;writing-mode: vertical-rl;
padding-right: 50px;">Some text</div>
</div>
```